# Command r.sunmask in GRASS

Tags: grass-gis, dem

I have hypsometric model of relief, and I need to visualize shadows. I was suggested to use GRASS command r.sunmask, so I tried to set time values and run command, but it gives me an error

```
"ERROR: Neither sun position nor east/north, date/time/timezone definition are complete"
```

So then I tried to put values in Position tab, which I founded by SOLPOS Calculator (http://www.nrel.gov/midc/solpos/solpos.html)

```
r.sunmask elevation=model@PLANINA output=model_sunmask year=2011 month=1 day=15 hour=9 timezone=1 east=45.909361 north=15.965538
```

But it didn't work out, too, it says "Calculating shadows from DEM..." but nothing's going on for hours of waiting. So I ask if that command works at all in GRASS, or I'm doing something wrong?

You can suggest some other application for same thing, except ArcGIS applications.

Comment: Could you post the command you used?

Comment: Do you need to visualize actual shadows or do you just need a shaded relief map?  For the latter, look at [r.shaded.relief](http://grass.osgeo.org/gdp/html_grass64/r.shaded.relief.html)

Comment: r.sunmask elevation=model@PLANINA output=model_sunmask year=2011 month=1 day=15 hour=9 timezone=1 east=45.909361 north=15.965538

Comment: I need to visualize actual shadows.

Comment: I haven't tried this, but I read that r.sun is faster and can be used by extracting 0 values from the incidout output.  The 0 values are shadows.  There is some debate about this here: http://osgeo-org.1803224.n2.nabble.com/long-run-time-with-r-sunmask-td1877017.html

Comment: There is too many parameters which I don't know for that command so I would rather that you suggest some new application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please use the [r.sun](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/html64_user/r.sun.html) command for this (-s for shadows). A map of shadows can be extracted from the solar incidence angle map ("incidout"): Areas with zero values are shadowed. Note that r.sunmask is terribly slow and r.sun the better choice.