# Calculating shadow of trees with DEM in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, dem, lidar, shadow

I have a DEM with a good precision (0,5 x 0,5 m/pix LiDAR) and I´m looking for the way to obtain a raster (or shapefile) with the shadow of the trees located in that place for a whole day (ideally winter solstice)

[image]

Is it possible with some tool to calculate it through QGIS?

My intention is to use this raster (or shape) with the maximum shadow to restrict the installation area of a solar power plant.

I have more information, like the height and canopy diameter of each tree.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [r.sun](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass74/manuals/r.sun.html) as suggested in [Command r.sunmask in GRASS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9491/command-r-sunmask-in-grass/9497#9497).

As the input to `r.sun` build a [DSM raster](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5701/differences-between-dem-dsm-and-dtm/57306#57306) from data (i.e., the trees must be part of the elevation raster, if they are not already).

---

<sub>GRASS 7.4</sub>

```
r.sun dsm day=355 time=9 incidout=shadowed_dsm
```

Pixels with NULL are shadowed.

---

<sub>GRASS 6.4</sub>

```
r.sun -s dsm day=355 time=9 incidout=shadowed_dsm
```

Pixels with zero values are shadowed.

---

Pick a day which correspond to winter solstice. Set a specific time of day (run `r.sun` varying the time of the day, and merge output rasters later).

Be aware of the Coordinate Reference System from the DSM. If coordinates are latitude-longitude (degrees), elevation units need to be in meters. Otherwise, x, y and z must have the same unit. Also, from `r.sun` documentation, the DSM must be a floating point (FCELL) raster.

After finding clear areas of shadows, consider studying if face orientation (aspect) will make a difference for the solar power plant location. If in the North hemisphere, perhaps choosing a south oriented surface will help.